# iOS: AutoresizingMask not resizing to fit map or view on screen

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, autoresizingmask

My views are not resizing correctly using something like:

self.someview.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight| UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth);

Using all the possible resizing masks did not solve the problem either. I am running iOS 5.1 on my phone and 6.0 on the simulator but the result is the same either way. I have attached pictures to better describe the problem. How can I set the autoresizingMask so the view ALWAYS fills the screen?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check the superview's `autoresizesSubviews` set to `YES` and you are not setting incorrect frame for the map at `layoutSubviews`. I've just added the map view and it resizes as expected.

The resizing mask I used is

```
UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin
```